# Chrome is unable to do array destructuring

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, destructuring

I have the following function:

```
function evaluateScroll(positions, width){
    var scale = width / (width - Math.abs(positions[0]) - Math.abs(positions[1]));
    var startLocation = positions[0] / width;

    return [scale, startLocation];
}
```

and I use it in the following way:

```
[tscale, tstartLocation] = evaluateScroll(scrollPositions, scrollPlotWidth);
```

In Safari and Firefox, it works as it would be expected to work. In Chrome, however, the code hangs-up at this line.

Changing it to:

```
var holder = evaluateScroll(scrollPositions, scrollPlotWidth);
```

works, but then I have to parse out the indexes of `holder` to the appropriate variables.

How come Chrome won't work with the array-style assignment? Is there a syntax that I can implement that would work across all browsers, without having to do the holder variable and reassigning to the appropriate ones?

Comment: What do you expect `[tscale, tstartLocation] = evaluateScroll(scrollPositions, scrollPlotWidth);` to do?  That doesn't look like valid syntax.

Comment: @RocketHazmat it is valid syntax for ES6

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment#Browser_compatibility

Comment: There is enough information on the internet to find out which browser supports which feature, for Chrome specifically: https://www.chromestatus.com/features/4588790303686656 . We really don't need such questions ("Does version X support Y") on Stack Overflow. We used to have a nice close reason for this.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is asking whether a Chrome supports a specific feature. Information about this already available (in much more up-to-date fashion) and this issue will quickly become irrelevant when Chrome does support it.

Comment: Use Babel if you want to write cross-platform ES6

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It appears chrome 48 (current stable) does not support the destructuring assignment syntax yet: https://kangax.github.io/compat-table/es6/#destructuring

Looks like it's good in 49+ though!

Comment: Word. I'll do it the old-fashioned way, for those who are not running the higher versions. One of those safe/sorry type of deals.

Comment: @Birrel it's ES6 syntax anyway. There's quite a few browsers that don't support ES6 yet.

Answer (score 1):

I suggest you to use Babel in order to write modern ES6/7 Javascript code.